# RXJS list selection stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a current problem I'd like to solve in an angular application. I could probably get it working without RXJS but I'd like to get better at streams.

So I have a list of checkboxes. These are defined by an interface of options {id: number, label: string}.

Now I want to pass in an Observable of {id: number, label: string} and then record what is selected and emit the selection every time a selection change has been made on a checkbox.

So I already have my options stream of {id: number, label: string}. My idea was to map that to another stream of type {id: number, label: string, selected: boolean}, then I would have a selectedOptions$ stream that filters off of the transformed stream, but I am stuck and not sure this is even the right approach.

```
options$: {id: number, label: string};
transformedOptions$: {id: number, label: string, selected: false}
selectedOptions$ = options$.map(options => options.filter((option) => option.selected));
```

Comment: you are on a right track. do you use reactive forms? if so, you might want to listen to `valueChange` observable on the form, filter that ine by selected checkboxes and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you get the value from onValueChange (or you can use onchange handler)

```
this.form.field.onValueChange.map(id=>{
// lets say you got the id as selected value
return options.filter(value=>options.id==id)[0]
}).subscribe()
```